# Checking if a record exists msql/php with if statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php - check record exists db - error show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317173/php-check-record-exists-db-error-show)

I am currently trying to add a user to the database. I want to to check if the user exists, and IF SO, then just update a few fields. If IT DOESNT, then it should completely insert a new record.

```
$result22 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM newsite WHERE user = '$username'");

if($result22){
$SQL = "UPDATE newsite SET active = '1' WHERE user = '$username'";
$_SESSION['username'] = $_GET['user'];
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
echo("lol."); // TEST
header("Location: ./share.php?user=$username");

}
if(!$result22){

$SQL = "INSERT INTO newsite (user, active) VALUES ('".$username."', '1')";
$_SESSION['username'] = $_GET['user'];
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
echo("NOPE."); //TEST
header("Location: ./share.php?user=$username");
}
}
```

I'm not really sure why, but no matter what it ALWAYS outputs "lol." (aka, the user exists.) it completely ignores the other if.

Comment: You have an extra closing brace. Not to mention you should combine it to just if ($result22) { ... } else { ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$result22 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM newsite WHERE user = '$username'");

if($result22){
```

Unless you have error in your SQL code, `mysql_query` returns **resultset** that is always resolved to `true`

Also:

[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [**prepared statements**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `mysql_num_rows` function, which returns the number of row of the last result set

```
if(mysql_num_rows()>0)
{

}
```